# failed to create function error because of name being too long

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While deploying my code I get the following error:

```
⚠  functions: failed to create function tests-testV2RefreshPodcast-testNewEpisodeMetadata
```

...

```
Functions deploy had errors. To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

my code looks like this:

```
exports.testNewEpisodeMetadata = functions.database.ref(testPath.getNewEpisodeScenarioTrigger()).onUpdate(() => {
    return Promise.all([])
})
```

Comment: Where is this string coming from?  "tests-testV2RefreshPodcast-"  With the code you're showing, I would expect the name of the function to be just "testNewEpisodeMetadata".

Answer (score 1):

Found out that it was because of a name size limit. Heres a valid path:

```
✔  functions[tests-testV2RefreshPodcast-testNewEpMeta]: Successful create operation.
```

Notice how I changed the name `testNewEpisodeMetadata` to `testNewEpMeta`

Comment: If you run the deploy with the debug flag `firebase deploy --debug`, the message of the error can be seen in the output: "maximum allowed length is 48"

Comment: But `testNewEpisodeMetadata` is well under that limit. Is `tests-testV2RefreshPodcast` a project prefix?